# Where in newly create column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have newly created column

```
        $query->select([
            "table1.*",
            DB::raw("
                CASE
                    WHEN table2.updated_at >= table1.updated_at
                        THEN table2.updated_at
                    ELSE table1.updated_at
                END as last_update
            ")
        ]);
```

Now I want to find table where last_update is between since and till, my current solution:

```
            $query->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where("table1.updated_at", '>=', $this->since);
                $query->orWhere("table2.updated_at", '>=', $this->since);
            });
```

```
            $query->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where("table1.updated_at", '>=', $this->till);
                $query->orWhere("table2.updated_at", '>=', $this->till);
            });
```

How can I use 'last_update' column or use where on column with has newer update_at?

Answer (score 1):

`$query->having("last_update", '>=', $this->since)`
Having resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can query `table1` and join `table2` and on both tables you can call the where clause:

```
Table1::with(['table2' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('updated_at', '>=', $this->since);
}])
->where('updated_at', '>=', $this->since)
->get();
```